# Unable to use LINQPAD4

Tags: c#, linqpad

I'm a new user using LINQPAD4.
LINQPAD 4 throws error when I type anything in the Query window...

For the below sentence

```
string[] names = { "Tom", "Dick", "Harry" };
```

I see

```
Invalid expression term 'string'

Syntax error; value expected

) expected

Invalid expression term '{'
```

Comment: what are you using C# Expression or C# Statement(s) or C# Program?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thats because you try to run this as a `C# Expression` in Linqpad. What you need it to set it to `C# Statement(s)` in the dropdown just above the code area.

The `C# Expression`-option is used if you want to try out pure Linq-statements against a datasource.